# Nash-Kuiper embedding of the hyperbolic plane into $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

According to [Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_theorem_(differential_geometry)), the $\mathbb{H}^2$ cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$. But then there's [Nash-Kuiper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) theorem, which states that a $C^1$ embedding exists.

How to reconcile these two results? My understanding so far is that measuring curvature requires at least $C^2$ embedding. Is that the difference here?

Follow-up questions:

1. How does the Nash embedding actually look like? Or is it just an existence result?
2. Nash embedding is still isometric, meaning I can measure tangent vectors. Intuitively that seems to imply that I can do things such as measuring curve lengths, angles, areas. But wouldn't that mean that I'm effectively able to measure curvature? What am I missing here?

Comment: In this case isometric embedding does *not* mean that you can measure tangent vectors. All it means is that the arc length of each curve is preserved under the embedding.

Comment: Could you elaborate? The Wiki article says: $g(v,w) = \langle df_\epsilon(v),df_\epsilon(w)\rangle$. If the inner product is preserved, then curve lengths, angles, areas, volumes etc. are also preserved, is that right?